# consumer consuming the same message twice at the starting only

Tags: api, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-python

At the very first consuming, my consumer is consuming the same 
    message twice, this only happens at the first consuming, after 
    that it only consumes once.

---

Attaching the consumer conf code below. please check for the corrections

```
def __init__(self, group_id, topic='default', bootstrap_servers= 
['localhost:9092']):
        self.topic = topic
        self.bootstrap_servers = bootstrap_servers
        self.group_id = group_id
        self.consumer = KafkaConsumer(## Heading ##
            self.topic,
            bootstrap_servers=self.bootstrap_servers,
            auto_offset_reset='earliest',
            enable_auto_commit=True,
            group_id=self.group_id,
            value_deserializer=lambda x: loads(x.decode('utf-8')))
```

Comment: Are you sure you actually consume the *same* message twice? and that you don't have 2 messages with the same content in your topic? Have you checked the message offsets?

Comment: yes i have checked the message offset.. it duplicates it only at the first consuming after when i restart..

Comment: @MickaelMaison  is there anything in the parameters that i am missing?